# How to access value from URL in smarty template?

Tags: php, smarty

I'm newbie in smarty so facing so much difficulties in using it.
I've got the following URL :

```
http://localhost/schooling_needs/sneeds1.0/web/control/modules/chapter_youtube_videos/chapter_youtube_videos.php?chapter_id=102
```

I want to assign the value of chapter_id to a text field in smarty template. For that I wrote following code, but it's not getting the correct value.

```
<input type="text" name="chapter_id" id="chapter_id" value="{$chapter_id}">
```

The text field is not getting any value. Would you please help me by telling how should I assign the value of `chapter_id` to the above textfield?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to assign it within your code to the smarty template you are using.  For example:

```
$smarty->assign('chapter_id', $_GET['chapter_id']);
```

before you `fetch`/`display` your template. ^^

Due to OP's limitations, using the built-in smarty instead of assigning to page individually.:

```
{$smarty.get.chapter_id}
```

would provide it directly from the `$_GET` array.

Comment: Actually I want to access the value from the URL. The URL is generated dynamically so I can't assign the value. Can you suggest any way to access the value of chapter_id from URL?

Comment: Hey buddy your trick worked for me. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No problem, happy to help ^^

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `$_GET` parameters in your template by using `$smarty.get.parametername`. So your code should look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="chapter_id" id="chapter_id" value="{$smarty.get.chapter_id}">
```

You can read more in the [Smarty documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.smarty.tpl)